# Text-align:center not working in CDATA in string.xml

Tags: android, html, css, xml, cdata

I want to center text with CDATA in string.xml. I used following but no result.

,  are working. But text-align="center" not working. I used also . but no result.I also used . again fail. no solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="my_talk"><![CDATA[<p text-align="center"><b>abcd</b></p></string>
</resources>
```

This is in MainActivity.java

```
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(this.getString(R.string.my_talk)));
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-align="center"` is not valid HTML/CSS. Perhaps you mean `style="text-align:center"`

Comment: I used but no change

Comment: The "]]>" (to end the cdata section) seems to be missing from the XML. If that doesn't cause the centering to work, we'll need to see more of your code. Also you may want to add the "java" tag to your question.